# Select unique value in many lists in python

Tags: python

I'd like to select unique value in many lists, but I don't know how to do that:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6] 
c = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

I'd like to make one new list which is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

I know that using the following could be done, but I am searching quicker way to do that.

```
for i in (a, b, c):
    for j in EachValueInEachList:
        NewList.append(j)
list(set(NewList)
```

By the way, there are thousand of lists in my real program.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you're looking for `set()`

Comment: So many ways to do this with `set()`, so many wrong ways to do it without `set()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [2,3,4,5,6]
>>> c = [5,6,7,8,9]
>>> list(set(a + b + c))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

To avoid creating temporary list, use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(set(itertools.chain(a, b, c)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**UPDATE** (answer to the comment)

If you have a list of lists, use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a_list_of_lists)))
```

Comment: How can I do this with thousand of lists ?

Comment: To make it clear to Jimmy, if there 1000s of lists are aggregated in some iterable (a list, a whatever) called my_lists then do:
     list(set(itertools.chain(my_lists)))

Comment: it's okay, I understand. Thank you very much. It's a quite brilliant way.

Comment: @Potrebic, I think you missed a `*` before `my_lists`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(set(a) | set(b) | set(c))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is best option if long list.

```
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.time()
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6],[5,6,7,8,9]])
print np.unique(a).tolist()
print time.time() - start_time  # Execution time
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
0.000999927520752
```